# Double For Loop Iteration. Two lists comparison

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

I'm a beginner.

Could you tell me why this script works **even though the `i` variable is not defined** in the `ip not in i` case?

The script compares a list of ARP table `match_data` (which I get from a  paramiko ssh connection), and my ip list `match_ip`. I just want to print the IP MAC, and if the IP is not in the ARP list table to `print ip + "NO MAC ADDRESS"`.

```
for ip in match_ip:
    for i in match_data:
        if ip in i:
            print  re.search((ip+'\s+'),i).group(0),mac.search(i).group(0)
            break
    if ip not in i:
        print ip + '           NO MAC ADDRESS'
```

#### Output

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Python2/Get_mac_from_arp.py
!!!Connecting SSH!!!
10.240.184.103           30e4.db80.b699
10.240.184.104          7c2f.802d.61e5
10.240.184.105          7c2f.8072.40fc
10.240.184.106          e05f.b982.5720
10.240.178.11           NO MAC ADDRESS
10.240.184.177          e05f.b982.5752
10.240.184.178          7c2f.802a.782a
10.240.184.179          30e4.db80.b6ec
10.240.184.180          7c2f.802a.782b

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Please verify that the indentation is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "the i variable is not defined?" In Python you don't declare variables

Comment: Why do you say that "the "i" variable is not defined in the `(ip not in i)` case". `i` still has the value it had at the end of the `for` loop.

Comment: Because, given that your indentation is correct, the `i` in `if ip not in i:` takes the last value of `i` it had in `for i in match_data:`

Comment: @zipa That `for` loop only breaks if `ip not in i`, thus the following `if ip not in i` block won't be entered in that case. It's only entered if the `for` loop terminates normally, that is, if no `ip in i` match is found.

Comment: `i` is a very poor name for this variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `i` is still valid at that point. It has the last value that it got assigned in the `for` loop. However, there's no need to actually have that `if` test following the loop. Python `for` and `while` loops take an optional `else` clause which is entered if the loop terminates normally, i.e. it isn't exited early due to a `break` statement (or a `return` statement).

So we can re-write that code as:

```
for ip in match_ip:
    for i in match_data:
        if ip in i:
            print  re.search((ip+'\s+'),i).group(0),mac.search(i).group(0)
            break
    else:
        # We can only get here if the `break` didn't happen
        print ip + '           NO MAC ADDRESS'
```

---

I suppose you expected a `for` loop to create a new scope, with the loop index and other variables created in the loop only existing in that scope. In some languages (especially those closely related to C) a new block creates a new scope, but that doesn't happen in Python with normal `for` loops. Python is more conservative with creating scopes, because they aren't as "cheap" to do as they are in C. A function definition creates a new local scope, and so does a class definition. However, a generator expression *does* run in its own scope, and so does a list comprehension in Python 3, in Python 2 a list comprehension runs in the scope of the surrounding code.

You can read about [scopes and namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) in the official tutorial.

---

BTW, you should seriously consider migrating to Python 3, Python 2 reaches its official End of Life some time in 2020.

Comment: I just merely understand why the "else" case is not expected under the "if  ip in i" as an alternative action =) And why is "break" word is necessary here (without break the script doesnt work properly)

Comment: @Dover The Python  interpreter knows that the `else` belongs to the `for` and not the preceding `if` because of the indentation. So you need to be **very** careful not to mess the indentation up when using `else` with `for` or `while`! The `break` is necessary because otherwise control will automatically go into the `else` block when the `for` terminates. Also `break` makes the code more efficient because we don't want to keep testing for matches after we've already found a match.

Answer (score 1):

> even though the "i" variable is not defined in the (ip not in i) case?

It *is* actually defined - by the  `for i in match_data` statement.

Comment: This is example why one should name their variables properly instead of using i and j in every for loop.

Comment: Isnt  the last "if" case must be under the "for i in match_data"?

Comment: @Dover Loops do *not* create a scope in Python

Comment: @Dover: depends on the expected result, but that's another question. Note that if you want it in the inner loop, it would be better written as an `else` clause.